# How to retrive data using colum name with python and mysql library

Tags: mysql, python-3.7

I know that we can retrieve data from **python mysql library** by index but i need to access them using column names is there any way to access them using mysql as i can see there is way to do this **MYSQLDB** but at the moment i have to change my whole code in 100 of files to use that way. i just need to is there any way to access them using column names with mysql

class file //

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.connetion = mysql.connector.connect(
                host="localhost",
                user="root",
                passwd="",
                database="leame",
                use_pure=True
            )

        except Error as e:
            print(e)

    def query(self, query, param="NULL"):
        mycursor = self.connetion.cursor(prepared=True)

        if param != "NULL":
            mycursor.execute(query, params=param)
        else:
            mycursor.execute(query)

        myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
        return myresult
```

object calling

```
    dbobj = new db() 
    came = dbobj.query("SELECT st_name,pwd FROM staff WHERE st_id = %s", ('1',))
    for x in came:
        print(x[1])
```

**with this approach it's working but i need other way around not index**
by using this i can access fields but i need to access them using like this x['column_name'] is there a way to do this using MYSQL library

Comment: If you share your current code it will be much easier for people to see how to help you.

Comment: @Nick thank you for your response i have edited my question